# Special relativity: and Lorentz transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

[image]

An astronaut travels in a spaceship from Earth to Mars, which is located $300LS$ (light seconds) from Earth.
The spaceship's velocity is $0.4c$. Both Earth and the spaceship have synchronized clocks $t'=t=0$ when the spaceship leaves Earth. At $t_A>0$ (Earth's time) a light message is sent to the spaceship "Good luck" and the astronaut receives the message at $t'_1=30 sec$ (spaceship clock). At $t_B>t_A$ (Earth's time) a light message is sent from Mars to the spaceship "Welcome" and the astronaut receives it at $t'_2= 330 sec$.

What is the value of $t_B-t_A$?
Answer: $184.4 secs$

Here's my approach:
The time (Earth wise) it took for the first message to arrive to the spaceship is $T_1=t_A+(0.4c*t_A)/c=1.4t_A$.

The time (Earth wise) it took for the second message to arrive to the spaceship is $T_2=t_B+(300*c*sec-0.4c*t_B)/c=0.6t_B+300$.

Lorentz transformation:

$T_1=\gamma*(t'_1)$

$T_2=\gamma*(t'_2)$

And the result I get is $t_B-t_A=76.719$

Where is my mistake? How should I approach these kind of questions?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 0):

$T_1=\gamma*(t'_1)$

$T_2=\gamma*(t'_2)$

Above both equations are correct. But

$T_1 \neq t_A+(0.4c*t_A)/c=1.4t_A$

$T_2 \neq  t_B+(300*c*sec-0.4c*t_B)/c=0.6t_B+300$

Check your calculations again.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$T_1=t_A+\dfrac{\text{distance covered by the light beam in the interval} [t_A,t_1] }{c}$

$T_2=t_B+\dfrac{\text{distance covered by the light beam in the interval} [t_B,t_2]}{c}$

You don't get the second terms in these two equations right. This is your only problem. Try to do it again. Your mistake was that you considered the distances traveled by the light beam *constant* during the intervals $ [t_A,t_1]$ and $[t_B,t_2]$, but they're not, since the spaceship is moving in those intervals.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Using this equation for the events in question make the first message received at 32.732seconds Earth time and the second message 360.0595seconds Earth time. The difference between them is 327.3275seconds.

Comment: He's asking for $t_B - t_A$. What you've calculated here is $T_2 -T_1$.

Comment: Is it in the Earths frame or the ships frame?

Comment: $t_B,t_A,T_2,T_1$ are all in the earth's frame.

Comment: I thank all of you for giving some of your time helping me, I've finally solved this problem. I built a table of events, found the two distances required and I've got the right answer.I feel much better now dealing with these kind of problems.